# Add all the TextViews and ImageViews in the same list

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-developer-api

I'm trying to create an app. I have 4 `TextViews`, and 4 `ImageViews`. If I want to put something else at the top of the layout, I have to move all 4 `TextViews` and all 4 `ImageViews` down, but I don't want to move them each separately (it takes more time). I`m thinking if there is any possibility to put all of them in a List or something like this, and move all of them only by one xml code.

For example

```
<TextView/>
 <ImageView/>
<TextView/>
 <ImageView/>
<TextView/>
 <ImageView/>
```

and move down all of them by one code to make free space for another `TextView` and `ImageView`.

Comment: How about putting them all in one layout, and moving the layout down?

Answer (score 1):

Are they all stacked up like that? Try putting them in a LinearLayout, then set attribute `layout_marginTop` to how much you want them to go down.